Combine queries and update existing lines from a specific row
I have this data, I did a union to generate the file like this
Main Number Type  Invoice Number  Amount       Payment Date  Payment Number       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
52837       13     365572         4000.00
52837       13     366643         5000.00
52837       24     XXXXX          9000.00      06/10/24      Check 123
52890       13     365590         6000.00
52890       13     384450         2500.00
52890       24     YYYYY          6500.00      06/12/24      Check 441 

Now I need to get the payment Date and Payment Number on the same line and eliminate the type of 24, so the result would be:
Main Number Type  Invoice Number  Amount       Payment Date  Payment Number       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
52837       13     365572         4000.00      06/10/24      Check 123  
52837       13     366643         5000.00      06/10/24      Check 123 
52890       13     365590         6000.00      06/12/24      Check 441
52890       13     384450         2500.00      06/12/24      Check 441


Any ideas on how to handle this?

"Any ideas on how to handle this?" (An UPDATE with) a "self JOIN" (and then a DELETE)? What is the diffculting you are having achieving your goal? What have you tried? Why isn't it working?

Use max window function to get the payment data over all the rows and then filter out the row you don't want

with dataX as (<your union query>), dataY as (select *, max("Payment Date") over (partition by "Main Number") as "PaymentDateMax" from dataX) select * from dataY where "Type" <> 24;

If you identify the "invoice" rows (using WHERE Type=24) then you can apply the values back to the non-invoice rows, matching on [Main Number] as that is common to both datasets.
Set up the dataset in a CTE (or you can use a temp table). You won't need to do this as you have the data already.
;WITH tmp_data AS (
  SELECT 
    CAST(52837 AS INT) as [Main Number],
    13 AS [Type],
    '365572' AS [Invoice Number],
    4000.00 AS amount,
    NULL AS [Payment Date],
    NULL AS [Payment Number]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    52837,
    13,
    '366643',
    5000.00,
    NULL,
    NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    52837,
    24,
    'XXXXX',
    9000.00,
    '06/10/24',
    'Check 123'
),

Next we identify the invoice record(s). In this case using Type=24.
;WITH invoices AS ( --remove ;WITH if you are including the data setup above
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    tmp_data
  WHERE
    [Type] = 24
)

Then we apply the "invoices" values to the "non-invoices" rows, matching on a common key, ensuring that we do not reinclude the "invoices" row:
SELECT
  t.[Main Number],
  t.[Type],
  t.[Invoice Number],
  t.amount,
  CONVERT(DATE, i.[Payment Date], 23) AS [Payment Date], -- see notes. Or you can use i.[Payment Date]
  i.[Payment Number]
FROM
  tmp_data AS t
    LEFT JOIN invoices AS i
      ON t.[Main Number] = i.[Main Number]
WHERE
  t.[Type] = 24

The LEFT JOIN is because it is possible that not every transaction has an invoice payment “[Type]=24” row.
Note re CONVERT(DATE, ..., 23) :
Date style 23 outputs the date value in the format yyyy-mm-dd, which is easy to sort on, as strings as well as date formats.
Note that this is not converting the date field, it is just formatting how the date is displayed.
If you leave out the CONVERT() then it will display in the default date format set for your session.  (H/T @Luuk)
Here is the help file for date output formatting in T-SQL.

I am not clear since there are values hard coded in your query.  I added additional examples and the output I need.
Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry, this statement is begging (IMHO) for a downvote: "Date style 23 converts and outputs the value in the format yyyy-mm-dd, which is easy to sort on, as strings as well as date formats."  because sorting should be done on the the DATE fields, and Definitely not on a DETE field converted to CHAR.  So CONVERT(...23) should only be used when that is needed for formatting output.

@Luuk it isn’t converting to CHAR, it is just how it formats the date when it displays. It is still a date field. It can be formatted to any of the date formats in the linked documentation. linked.

Ok, it is not converting to a string, but it still not clear why you need CONVERT, because a DATE should display in your favorite default format anyways... (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21327427/724039 )

@Luuk Okay that’s fair. In my TSQL days that wasn’t something I experienced. Useful to know.
That said, if the default format is not the one you prefer, the CONVERT() option is available.
Why I chose YYYY-MM-DD: because the year should not (IMO, no scientific reason) be in 2-digit format, and in YYYY-MM-DD format (style 23) there is no risk of confusing month and day.

@mjruttenberg: Luckily Americans have chosen a default format (MM/DD/YYYY) which does not make sense to normal people...

@brian-branco: The values were only in the script so I could replicate your data, as I don’t have access to your data. Of course you won’t need to do that. I have amended the script so you start at ";WITH invoices". I also added some clarifications. to my answer, including the result of the discussion above with luuk.

WITH source_data AS (
    /*
       UNION query for the existing data goes here
    */
)
SELECT sd1.[Main Number], sd1.Type  sd1.[Invoice Number], sd1.Amount,
    sd2.[Payment Date], sd2.[Payment Number]
FROM source_data sd1
INNER JOIN source_data sd2 ON sd2.[Main Number] = sd1.[Main Number]
    AND sd2.Type = 24
WHERE sd1.Type <> 24

